# How to properly test a revert for 'onlyOwner' modifier?

Tags: solidity, truffle, openzeppelin

In my Solidity contract that inherits from OpenZeppelin's `Ownable` and `AccessControl` I have a function that the contract owner can call to give an account the `ADMIN` role. It looks like this:

```
function addAdmin(address account) public virtual onlyOwner {
   _grantRole(ADMIN, account);
}
```

In my test file I am using OpenZeppelin's `test-environment` and `test-helper` with Mocha and Chai. I'm trying to test for the failure of calling `addAdmin()` from a non-owner account. My test looks like this:

```
it('denies access to non-Owners to add a new ADMIN', async function() {
   await expectRevert(
      await pool.addAdmin(notlisted1, { from: notlisted2 }),
      "Ownable: caller is not the owner"
   );
});
```

It appears that `addAdmin()` correctly reverts but the test fails. The message I see at the command line when this test fails is:

```
Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Ownable: caller is not the owner -- Reason given: Ownable: caller is not the owner.
```

Any thoughts on what's going on here? Why doesn't the `expectRevert()` assert pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually a simple mistake. Using `await` before `pool.addAdmin()` was incorrect. Removing that solved this issue.